# Trying to convert a big tsv file to json

Tags: python, json, csv

I've a tsv file, which I need to convert it into a json file. I'm using this python script which is exporting a empty json file.

```
import json
data={}
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile,open("data.tsv","r") as f:
for line in f:
   sp=line.split()
   data.setdefault("data",[])
json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: You never do anything with your `sp` variable. You only set the default 'data' attribute of your `data` variable to empty string.

Comment: Your program does not copy the values from sp to data. No wonder they aren't there when you write the output.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by pandas , but am not sure about performance

[df.to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

```
 df = pd.read_csv('data.tsv',sep='\t') # read your tsv file 
 df.to_json('data.json') #save it as json . refer orient='values' or 'columns' as per your requirements
```

Answer (score 1):

You never use the `sp` in your code.

To properly convert the tsv, you should read the first line separately, to get the "column names", then read the following lines and populate a list of dictionaries.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
import json
data=[{}]
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile, open("data.tsv","r") as f:
firstline = f.readline()
columns = firstline.split()
lines = f.readlines()[1:]
for line in lines:
    values = line.split()
    entry = dict(zip(columns, values))
    data.append(entry)
json.dump(data, outfile)
```

This will output a file containing a list of tsv rows as objects.