# How can I render a TSV file into JSON when it is saved as .txt?

Tags: c#, json, csv, oop

I have a very large table saved as a text file that is imported to my company from an external source. The formatting in this file looks like it should be a .TSV. I need to find a way to get it into an Observable Collection. My thought was that I could use a Deserializer to automatically parse it out. That didnt work at all since I dont have any quotes saved in the whole document. Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285033/trying-to-convert-a-big-tsv-file-to-json). The answer from giotskhada, seems like it would work, but its in Python, and I dont have a median file to save it into. Here is an example of the txt file:

```
id     FieldName1     FieldName2     FieldName3     FieldName4
1     test1           test3     test4
2           test2     test3     test4
3     test1     test2     test3     test4
```

and this is how I would like it to read out:

```
[ {"id":"1",
   "FieldName1":"test1",
   "FieldName2":"null",
   "FieldName3":"test3",
   "FieldName4":"test4"}
  },
  {"id":"2",
   "FieldName1":"null",
   "FieldName2":"test2",
   "FieldName3":"test3",
   "FieldName4":"test4"}
  },      
  {"id":"3",
   "FieldName1":"test1",
   "FieldName2":"test2",
   "FieldName3":"test3",
   "FieldName4":"test4"}
  ]
```

What can I do to make this happen in C#?

Comment: First thing, your desired output is not valid [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).  (You can check it [here](https://jsonlint.com/).)  Do you actually want that specific output, or do you want JSON?

Comment: Yes, well kindof. i want to be able to read it into a collection<object> so that i can recreate the Slowly Changing Dimension logic that sorts the the objects and compares them to entries already existing in the database. I have edited the question to show JSON though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you open to use external library, [Cinchoo ETL](https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL) is one will help to achieve to handle large file in expected format.

> install-package ChoETL.JSON

Here is sample working code

```
string tsv = @"id   FieldName1  FieldName2  FieldName3  FieldName4
1   test1       test3   test4
2       test2   test3   test4
3   test1   test2   test3   test4";

StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();

using (var r = ChoTSVReader.LoadText(tsv)
    .WithFirstLineHeader()
    )
{
    using (var w = new ChoJSONWriter(json))
        w.Write(r);
}

Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
```

**Output:**

```
[
 {
  "id": "1",
  "FieldName1": "test1",
  "FieldName2": null,
  "FieldName3": "test3",
  "FieldName4": "test4"
 },
 {
  "id": "2",
  "FieldName1": null,
  "FieldName2": "test2",
  "FieldName3": "test3",
  "FieldName4": "test4"
 },
 {
  "id": "3",
  "FieldName1": "test1",
  "FieldName2": "test2",
  "FieldName3": "test3",
  "FieldName4": "test4"
 }
]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. i will give this a shot and let you know!

Comment: This worked perfectly... Thank you!! Now I just gotta get it into the collection